# Nestjs with GraphQL: How to pass where clause in @Arg of a @Resolver method?

Tags: graphql, nestjs, prisma, prisma-graphql

I want to make a Graphql Resolver in Nestjs accept the where clause, which is then used by the Prisma Service in order to dynamically accept different search types for a given resource. What I have right now is:

```
//task.resolver.ts

  @Resolver((of) => Task)
  export class TaskResolver {
   constructor(private repository: TaskRepository) {}

   @Query((returns) => [Task])
   @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
   async tasks(
    @Args('where', { type: () => <Dont know the type> }) where: Prisma.TaskWhereInput,
   ) {
     return await this.repository.tasks({
       where,
     });
   }
}
```

I simply want the resolver method to be able to process a where clause such as :

```
// GraphQL client query

  query GetTasks($id: ID!, $level: Int!) {
    tasks(
      where: { user: { id: $id }, taskTemplate: { level: $level } }
    ) {
      id
      state
      taskTemplate {
        title
        level
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference

Comment: How does it answer my question?

Comment: you're using generator ... check/learn what is generated [and why/what depends of/etc/]